# Comparative performance of Hadoop Zlib and JDK Gzip

Tags: multithreading, hadoop, java-native-interface, compression, zlib

I am doing some benchmarking of single-threaded compression codecs, and the performance I see for Zlib seems significantly higher than what you would expect for a single thread. I have used `org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.zlib.ZlibCompressor`for the Zlib compressor implementation, and `java.util.zip.Deflate` for Gzip implementation to compare with.

Is ZLib compressor (wrapper) provided in Hadoop in some ways multi-threaded, perhaps through JNI interface?

**Zlib:**

```
import org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.zlib.*;
protected final zlibCompressor = new ZlibCompressor(ZlibCompressor.CompressionLevel.DEFAULT_COMPRESSION, ZlibCompressor.CompressionStrategy.DEFAULT_STRATEGY, ZlibCompressor.CompressionHeader.DEFAULT_HEADER, DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE);
protected final zlibDecompressor = new ZlibDecompressor(ZlibDecompressor.CompressionHeader.DEFAULT_HEADER, DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE);

//compress
zlibCompressor.setInput(uncompressed, 0, uncompressed.length);
zlibCompressor.finish();
int n = zlibCompressor.compress(compressBuffer, 0, compressBuffer.length);

//decompress
zlibCompressor.reset();
zlibDecompressor.setInput(compressed, 0, compressed.length);
int n = zlibDecompressor.decompress(uncompressBuffer, 0, uncompressBuffer.length);
```

**Gzip:**

```
import java.util.zip.*;
protected final deflater = new Deflater(COMPRESSION_LEVEL, NO_WRAP);
protected final inflater = new Inflater(NO_WRAP);

//compress
int n = compressBlockUsingStream(uncompressed, compressBuffer);

//decompress
inflater.reset();
int n = uncompressBlockUsingStream(new InflaterInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(compressed), _inflater), uncompressBuffer);
```

---

**Helper funtions for Gzip:**

```
protected int compressBlockUsingStream(byte[] uncompressed, byte[] compressBuffer) throws IOException
{
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream(compressBuffer);
        compressToStream(uncompressed, out);
        return out.length();
}    

protected int uncompressBlockUsingStream(InputStream in, byte[] uncompressBuffer) throws IOException
{
            ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream(uncompressBuffer);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
            int count;
            while ((count = in.read(buffer)) >= 0) {
                out.write(buffer, 0, count);
            }
            in.close();
            out.close();
            return out.length();
}
```

**Throughput:**

> Zlib/block      --  143.902 MBps
>
> Gzip/JDK/stream --  22.573  MBps

Anyone has an idea why zlib is so much faster (using all cores natively)? The code is expected to run single-threaded. Anyone is able to replicate similar result?

Answer (score 1):

java.util.zip uses zlib.

Are you sure that you you're using the same compression level in both? Is `COMPRESSION_LEVEL` equal to `ZlibCompressor.CompressionLevel.DEFAULT_COMPRESSION`?

Comment: OK, do you know what value " "DEFAULT_COMPRESSION" is [0 - 9]? Like to set it explicitly.

Comment: You can't print it?

Comment: Well, if you take a look at the Hadoop zlibcompressor code on github, you will see that its set to an integer value of -15. What does -15 mean? Compression levels range from 0 - 9 as far as I can tell.

Comment: It looks like [-1](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/f67237cbe7bc48a1b9088e990800b37529f1db2a/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/io/compress/zlib/ZlibCompressor.java#L119) to me.

Comment: What does -1 mean?

Comment: It's the integer on the number line before zero.

Comment: Ok, -1 means the compression level that zlib thinks is a good balance between speed and compression ratio. Currently zlib uses level 6 when -1 is provided. In any case, make sure that the same level, -1 in this case, is provided to both instances of zlib when trying to compare their speed.